# How to parse [object Object]

Tags: javascript, parsing

I don't know how to parse the value from response. I need to get a value according to key and values in individual strings but couldn't make it work

**here my sample code**

```
[
{"columns":
["campName","page_visits","filter_types","searchUrl","pageNo"],
"values":[["kk","2","All","https://www.google.com/search/results/people/?keywords=kk&origin=SWITCH_SEARCH_VERTICAL",1]]}]
```

I want `campName`,`page_visits`,`filter_types`,`searchUrl`,`pageNo` values to be stored as a string in javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: i tried its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store these values in an object:

```js
const data = [{
  "columns": ["campName", "page_visits", "filter_types", "searchUrl", "pageNo"],
  "values": [
    ["kk", "2", "All", "https://www.google.com/search/results/people/?keywords=kk&origin=SWITCH_SEARCH_VERTICAL", 1]
  ]
}]

const result = data[0].columns.reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
  acc[curr] = data[0].values[0][index];
  
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: i need value for campName  = kk , page_visits = 2, filter_types = All

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object using `array#reduce`

```js
var arr = [{"columns":["campName","page_visits","filter_types","searchUrl","pageNo"],"values":[["kk","2","All","https://www.google.com/search/results/people/?keywords=kk&origin=SWITCH_SEARCH_VERTICAL",1]]}];

var result = arr[0].columns.reduce((o, a, i) => {
  o[a] = arr[0].values[0][i];
  return o;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: That is the same answer as Erazihel gave a few minutes earlier, why duplicate it?